# Solving a system of 3 quadratic simultaneous equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x, y, z$ are positive real numbers which satisfy the following three equations.
$$x + 2y + z = 5(x + y)(y + z)$$
$$x + y + 2z = 7(y + z)(z + x)$$
$$2x + y + z = 6(z + x)(x + y)$$

Find the value of $(24)^3(xyz)$.

Okay , so here I'm probably not supposed to solve these equations , but rather find some "trick" to calculate $xyz$.
First thing that came to my mind was adding all three equations , which gives :
$$6 x^2+18 x y+18 x z+5 y^2+18 y z+7 z^2 = 4 (x+y+ z)$$
Now what? Any hints are apreciated. (This is not class-homework , I'm solving sample questions for a competitive exam )

Comment: Observe that $$x+y+y+z=x+2y+z $$  set $$x+y=a,y+z=b,z+x=c$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I'll try that , thanks.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I solved the question , thanks a lot for the hint!

Comment: If you have solved the question, please post a solution (and accept it, when the software allows it). It gives you practice in writing things up, and it helps keep the Unanswered Questions list in order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I posted the answer .

Answer (score 6):

Let $ x+y=a,y+z=b,z+x=c$.  (From labbhattacharjee's hint in comments)
Hence the equations become ,
$$a + b =5ab$$
$$c+b=7cb$$
$$a+c=6ca$$
These can be easily solved to give ,
$b=1/3, c=1/4,a=1/2$
Now back substitute $a=x+y,b=y+z,c=z+x$
Then the equations become , 
$$y+z=1/3$$
$$x+y=1/2$$
$$z+x=1/4$$
Now these equation can be easily solved to give ,
$$z=1/24$$
$$x=5/24$$
$$y=7/24$$
Hence $24*24*24*xyz=35$

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for your post answering your question and showing your effort. Cheers.